# PHP. Перезаписывает данные в массив

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно данные записывать в массив, но цыкл когда бежит, он их перезаписывает. Как сделать так, чтобы добавляло туда данные, а не перезаписывало?
Чтобы мои данные выглядели так
[0] => 
arrray (
 [0] => name1
 [1] => name2
)

```
$dataCategories = $modelCategories::find()->select(['*'])->orderBy(['name' => SORT_DESC])->all();
    $arrayCategories = [];
    foreach($dataCategories as $arrayDataCategories ){
        $arrayCategories[] = [
            $arrayDataCategories->id  => $arrayDataCategories->name
        ];
    }
    echo"<pre>";
    var_dump($arrayCategories);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = [];
foreach($dataCategories as $arrayDataCategories) {
    $items[$arrayDataCategories->id] = $arrayDataCategories->name;
}
$arrayCategories = [];
array_push($arrayCategories, $items);
```

Comment: Получаю 2 массива. А мне нужно чтобы всё было в [0]массиве.

Comment: Я немного поправил вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @DenisMaksiura Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.